# Creating and using M2M (machine to machine) tokens for auth in firebase for cross function authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

How do you create and use M2M (machine to machine) tokens in firebase auth for authenticating requests between functions?

In my case has function A calling function B but I want function B endpoint to be authenticated and only callable by function A.

On function B I have authentication in place as per this official sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint. This validates an incoming access token using the admin sdk and returns a forbidden response if validation fails. I've tested this with a user token (after logging in) and it works as expected.

My problem is that I have a separate userBeforeCreate function (function A) that makes a call into function B using node-fetch. As function B is authenticated I need an access token to attach - which I understand should be generated from a service account.

If I uderstand things correctly the question I'm asking is how do I get an access token from a service request?

Comment: What is `M2M token`? Edit your post, show the code you are using and the error message or stack trace. Cloud Functions require OIDC Identity Tokens for authentication.

Comment: M2M is machine to machine - I've edited the post to include the full name.

Comment: There is no difference between OIDC Identity Tokens for users and service accounts. In Google Cloud, services are assigned a service account to use for identity. Edit your post to provide the requested information and to clearly identify a problem.

Comment: I've tried adding more detail and a link to the sample I'm using. I'm not getting any specific error messages. I've not really got any code to post either as I'm mostly calling the endpoints using postman and haven't been able to create the access token from the service account as of yet

Comment: Postman is not going to help you with this problem. You must write code and call the service's endpoint. Start by reading the documentation on Cloud Function authentication. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating OIDC ID Tokens require an audience which is the URL of the service you are calling. That means either using a service account directly (RSA signing) or calling the metadata server to create the correct token. Postman cannot do that for you inside a Function without jumping thru many hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication primarily focuses on user authentication for applications, meaning it's designed to authenticate individual users rather than facilitating a full-fledged machine-to-machine (M2M) authentication flow. Firebase Authentication is more geared towards authenticating users with common authentication methods like email and password, phone number, Google Sign-In, etc.

However, Firebase does provide a way to authenticate a server or a backend service using a service account, which could be seen as a form of M2M authentication. This service account can be used to authenticate your backend servers or scripts to access Firebase services or APIs securely. This is particularly useful if you have a backend service that needs to interact with Firebase services directly, without involving end-users in the authentication process.

Keep in mind that Firebase Authentication might not provide the same level of M2M authentication features as specialized solutions that focus specifically on M2M authentication scenarios, such as OAuth-based M2M flows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).